# How to set partial text as as bold font to LabelField in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I don't know how to set partial text as a Bold to LabelField in Blackberry.

Kindly refer the attached image,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Format-text-in-a-RichTextField/ta-p/445038) example should contain everything you'll need. Your code should look something like this:

```
        String copyText = "Tap NEXT to proceed";
        Font[] fonts = new Font[2];
        fonts[0] = Font.getDefault();
        fonts[1] = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD);

        int[] offsets = new int[4];
        offsets[0] = 0;
        offsets[1] = "Tap ".length
        offsets[2] = "Tap NEXT".length;
        offsets[3] = copyText.length();

        byte[] attributes = new byte[3];
        attributes[0] = 0;
        attributes[1] = 1;
        attributes[2] = 0;

        RichTextField textField = new RichTextField(copyText, offsets, attributes, fonts, NON_FOCUSABLE);
        add(textField);
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you please also let me know how to calculate offsets and attributes if i am having other text like more than 20 words in one sentence. thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Pretty much the same as in the example, just larger. Each entry in the attributes array corresponds to the index in fonts to change to. These changes occur at the corresponding indexes in offsets. Ie, at offsets[0], fonts[attributes[0]] will be applied. Offsets should always have one more entry than attributes, for the copyText.length.   As for calculating the offsets, these will most likely be applied on hard coded strings, so you could literally count the characters if you'd like. I prefer typing the string and getting the length for readability.

Comment: for example: “on the next screen, enter your 5 digits to activate your account.

Tab NEXT to proceed.”

in this text NEXT should be bold. can you please help me in this.

Comment: The length of that text up to the NEXT is 70. Including the NEXT is 74. So if you change `copyText` to that string, the following offsets will give you a bold next
        offsets[0] = 0;
        offsets[1] = 70;
        offsets[2] = 74;
        offsets[3] = copyText.length();

Comment: useful link http://blackberry-digger.blogspot.in/2009/03/how-to-format-text-in-richtextfield.html